# Does anyone know piwik_auth cookie structure?

Tags: cookies, matomo

I'm new to piwik and I'm trying to understand all the cookies, now I'm whith the piwik_auth cookie, does anyone know how it works or what is its structure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see both in Piwik's [`SessionInitializer`](https://github.com/piwik/piwik/blob/master/plugins/Login/SessionInitializer.php) code, particularly following the application's flow starting in the `processSuccessfulSession()` method. If there's a particular part that's confusing, I might be able to provide a more specific answer.